# How to create an order from a cart in Mongoose and delete cart

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to:
a) Create an order from my current cart
b) Populate the response of the order with the selected object attributes in the "select"
c) Finally, I would like to delete the cart.

I have tried the below but here are my problems:

1. the result response does not come back populated even if the `prevProductsQuantity` constant is indeed populated
2. I created the function cartClear to receive the cart id and delete the document from the model but it is not working.
3. I am able to create many "same" orders so I think i need to manage with a conditiona but not sure where.

The response I am looking for:

```
{
"success": true,
"data": {
  "_id": "607ed5c425ae063f7469a807",
  "userId": "6071aed0ed7ec9344cf9616c",
  "productsQuantity": [
    {
      "_id": "607f2507994d5e4bf4d91879",
      "productId": {
        "productRef": "463b8bb7-6cf6-4a97-a665-ab5730b69ba2",
        "productName": "table",
        "brand": "boehm llc",
        "price": 713,
        "__v": 0,
        "createdAt": "2021-04-09T18:31:43.430Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-04-09T18:31:43.430Z"
      },
      "quantity": 2,
      "updatedAt": "2021-04-21T15:12:51.894Z",
      "createdAt": "2021-04-21T15:12:51.894Z"
    }
  ],
  "__v": 0
}
```

++ THE DELETION OF THE CART ++

The current response I am getting:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "data": {
    "state": "pending-payment",
    "_id": "6080507a0c758608d0dc585c",
    "userId": "6071aed0ed7ec9344cf9616c",
    "totalPrice": 1426,
    "productsQuantity": [
      {
        "_id": "607f2507994d5e4bf4d91879",
        "productId": "60709d8f24a9615d9cff2b69",
        "quantity": 2,
        "updatedAt": "2021-04-21T15:12:51.894Z",
        "createdAt": "2021-04-21T15:12:51.894Z"
      }
    ],
  "createdAt": "2021-04-21T16:19:06.056Z",
  "updatedAt": "2021-04-21T16:19:06.056Z",
  "__v": 0
}
```

** AND THE CART IS NOT DELETING **

this is the code I typed for these purposes.

Any guidance is super appreciated

```html
router.post('/', [isAuthenticated], async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const cart = await CartModel.findOne({ userId: req.user }).populate({
      path: 'productsQuantity.productId',
      select: {
        price: 1,
        brand: 1,
        productName: 1,
        productRef: 1,
        pictures: 1
      }
    });

    const prevProductsQuantity = cart
      .get('productsQuantity')
      .map((el) => el.toObject());

    const totalPriceByProduct = prevProductsQuantity.map(
      (product) => product.productId.price * product.quantity
    );
    const totalPrice = totalPriceByProduct.reduce(function (a, b) {
      return a + b;
    });

    const result = await OrderModel.create({
      userId: req.user,
      totalPrice: totalPrice,
      state: 'pending-payment',
      productsQuantity: prevProductsQuantity
    });

    const cartClear = (id) =>
      CartModel.deleteOne({
        _id: id._id
      });

    res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      data: result
    });
    cartClear(`${cart._id.toString()}`);
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not resolving the deleteOne promise, missing async & await.

```
const cartClear = async (id) =>
  CartModel.deleteOne({
    _id: id
  });

 await cartClear(`${cart._id.toString()}`)
 res.status(200).json({
   success: true,
   data: result
 });
```

Comment: you were right I wasnt handling the promise correctly..  i used  this and it worked: CartModel.findByIdAndDelete(cartId, function (err) {
      if (err) console.log(err);
      console.log('Successful deletion');
    }); // Thanks for the hint